# Apply a branching logic for an entire section in a REDCap instrument

Tags: redcap

How can I apply a branching logic for an entire section. At present, I have to do it to individual questions within the section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized redcap does not have an easy way to do this except via exporting the data dictionary and copy pasting the branching logic across all questions of interest then re-importing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a sufficiently recent version (version 12.0.0, released 2021-11-22), you can employ form display logic; that is, apply branching logic to the display of an entire form.

Prior to its inclusion in the core code, this functionality was provided by an external module called 'form render skip logic'.

Ask your local admin for advice.

Comment: "Form Display Logic" was introduced in version 12.0.0 (released on 2021-11-22).  For REDCap admins: https://community.projectredcap.org/articles/13/index.html

Comment: Thanks @wibeasley. I have incorporated this info into the answer.

Comment: In my experience, form display logic works poorly with surveys. It's good with staff-side forms.